# Ao definir que subpropriedade no mapeamento do EF via Fluent API deveria ser ignorada é lançado uma ArgumentException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, fluent-api

Criei um mapeamento no **Entity Framework** via **Fluent API**, porem ao definir que uma subpropriedade deveria ser ignorada é lançado a exceção abaixo:

> **System.ArgumentException**: 'The expression 'x =>
>   x.PaisCompleto.Descricao' is not a valid property expression. The
>   expression should represent a simple property access: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'.'

**Mapeamento**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new EnderecoMap());
    }
}

public class EnderecoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Endereco> builder)
    {
        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.PaisCompleto, pais => {

                pais
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("PaisCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(5)");
            });
        builder.Ignore(x => x.PaisCompleto.Descricao);// Lança exceção

        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.CidadeCompleto, cidade => {

                cidade
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("CidadeCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(7)");
            });
        builder.Ignore(x => x.CidadeCompleto.Descricao);// Lança exceção
    }    
}
```

**Entidades Mapeadas**

```
public abstract class Endereco
{
    public DtoConceito<string> CidadeCompleto { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
}

public class DtoConceito<T>
{    
    public T Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível ignorar subpropriedades no Entity Framework.

A maneira correta de ignorá-la seria no mapeamento da entidade país.

Segue exemplo:

```cs
public class EnderecoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Endereco> builder)
    {
        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.PaisCompleto, pais => {

                pais
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("PaisCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(5)");

                pais.Ignore(c => c.Descricao);
            });

        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.CidadeCompleto, cidade => {

                cidade
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("CidadeCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(7)");

                cidade.Ignore(c => c.Descricao);
            });
    }    
}
```